# Flutter : Custom UI for Scan QR Reader. Do let me know any plugin so that I can make menus at the bottom of Scanning screen

Tags: dart, flutter, qr-code, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Worked on using following plugins but didn't get any solution:

```
path_provider: 0.4.1
barcode_scan: ^0.0.4
qr_flutter: ^1.1.1
zxing: ^0.0.4+1
```

Answer (score 3):

i like to introduce new Plugin [**qr_mobile_vision: ^0.1.0**](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/qr_mobile_vision#-installing-tab-) which may help You to do so.

Comment: Just an FYI with that plugin - it uses Google's mobile vision library which will eventually be EOL'd. Before that it'll be transitioned to either using firebase mobile vision (which is the successor to the Google mobile vision library) or maybe a 3rd party solution. Im the one who made it, but I haven't decided what to do yet. If it switches to using firebase, you'll have to have a firebase account set up though so I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks. Got another plugin that worked for me.
[fast_qr_reader_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fast_qr_reader_view)